Unable to install or load mod br_netfilter and overlay in container on proxmox
I’m new to Proxmox and have recently installed Proxmox 8.2.0 with kernel version 6.8.4-2. I’m trying to set up k3s in an LXC container because I prefer the lightweight nature of containers over VMs. However, I’m running into issues with the k3s service due to missing modules: br_netfilter and overlay.
I’ve researched extensively and tried over 30 different solutions, including downgrading the kernel to version 6.5.13-5, but the problem persists.
Has anyone else faced this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? I’d greatly appreciate any help or advice!
Thanks in advance!
